# constexpr typed non-dynamic uninitialized storage

Tags: c++, c++20

In C++20, we have

```cpp
constexpr T* std::allocator<T>::allocate( std::size_t n );
```

to allocate *typed* dynamic uninitialized storage (and `construct_at` to construct objects) in compile-time.

But do we have *typed* non-dynamic storage in compile-time, for example, a *typed* `aligned_storage`?

---

Edit: One useful usage of this is to implement constexpr static_vector:

```
template<class T, size_t Cap>
class static_vector {
    size_t size;
    Storage<T, Cap> storage;
};
```

Comment: Wasn't it the purpose of `std::launder` to type what was returned by `std::aligned_storage`?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I think I can't construct objects in `aligned_storage` in compie-time since it's not a *typed* storage. `construct_at` requires a `T*` storage but `reinterpret_cast` is not allowed in compile-time. And I think `launder` is not related to this question because it's purpose is different and it's for alread-constructed objects.

Comment: Can you add a code example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: [p1413](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1413r2.pdf) gives a pretty good overview of why `aligned_*` cannot be used in `constexpr`

Comment: @AndyG One useful usage of this is to implement constexpr static_vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `std::array<std::optional<T>, Cap>`, or implement it yourself with a `union` if you don't want the overhead of each value in the array having its own boolean. C++17 gave us the ability to activate a union member in `constexpr` when there's no active member yet, and C++20 lets us change the active member in `constexpr` as long as you follow the proper object lifetime rules. Note that there are very few ways to activate `union` members or change which member is active - in particular, [you cannot use pointer-to-member syntax to activate a union member](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76124440/1959975).

Here's an example of the `union` approach: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/h6djsYshr

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <memory>
#include <new>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace example
{
    struct None {};
    template<class T, std::size_t Cap>
    struct Storage
    {
        union U
        {
            None none;
            T some;
            constexpr U() noexcept : none{} {}
        };
        U values[Cap];
    };
    template<class T, std::size_t Cap>
    class static_vector
    {
        std::size_t size{};
        Storage<T, Cap> storage;
    public:
        constexpr ~static_vector() noexcept
        {
            for(std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            {
                std::destroy_at(&storage.values[i].some);
            }
        }
        template<typename... Args>
        constexpr T& emplace_back(Args&&... args)
        {
            if(size >= Cap)
            {
                throw std::bad_alloc();
            }
            auto& u{storage.values[size]};
            std::construct_at(&u.some, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            ++size;
            return u.some;
        }
    };
}
namespace example_usage
{
    struct CounterHolder
    {
        int& counter;
        constexpr CounterHolder(int& counter_) noexcept
        : counter{counter_}
        {
        }
    };
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr int demo() noexcept
    {
        example::static_vector<CounterHolder, 10> v;
        int counter{};
        ++v.emplace_back(counter).counter;
        ++v.emplace_back(counter).counter;
        ++v.emplace_back(counter).counter;
        return counter;
    }
    static constexpr int const demoResult{demo()};
    [[nodiscard]] int showDemoResultInAssembly() noexcept
    {
        return demoResult;
    }
}
```